# IE Alternative Windows Embedded Compact 7 - modern jQuery and Javascript support

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, windows-embedded-compact

I am developing a web application to be used on Motorola(Symbol) RF barcode scanners. The scanners run on Windows Embedded Compact 7 and come loaded with their own version of IE. For the life of me I cannot find what version of IE this is, but the closest approximation I was able to find is 6.0. Javascript does not always work properly on this browser and jquery mobile UI components do not  seem to work at all.

Is there an alternative browser that I could use in place of IE that is compatible with Win Embedded compact 7 that allows for javascript and jquery support?

Comment: print the user agent, and you will find what version it is.

Comment: load up an older version of jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some vendors of WEC7 devices offer alternative browsers. For example Honeywell/Intermec offer HTML5 browser based on webkit, Motorola/Zebra offer RhoMobile (also that is not only a browser).

You may also go with ZetaKey HTML5 browser.

Remember that these devices still have limitted resources and so the browsers are limitted too in there feature set or resource usage.